# Lua get index name of table as table

Tags: indexing, lua, lua-table

Is there any way to get every index value of a table?

Example:

```
local mytbl = {
    ["Hello"] = 123,
    ["world"] = 321
}
```

I want to get this:

```
{"Hello", "world"}
```

Comment: `local a={}; for k in pairs(mytbl) a[#a + 1]=k end`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
local t = {}
for k, v in pairs(mytbl) do
  table.insert(t, k)  -- or t[#t + 1] = k
end
```

Note that the order of how `pairs` iterates a table is not specified. If you want to make sure the elements in the result are in a certain order, use:

```
table.sort(t)
```